# Suppress Entity Framework Core Queries logging for an specific query or context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP core MVC app and inside it a background task that run a query every 5 seconds, some things like this:

```
var dbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

var files = await dbContext.Set<File>().Where(...).ToListAsync();
```

The problem is it fills my output with this log:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) ...
```

I know it's possible to change the global DB Context settings or log level to make ef log completely silent but I'm searching for a way to suppress log query of **only** this command or db context.

Comment: Are you using the default logger? With Serilog you could implement an ILogEventFilter and skip single logs on whatever condition.

Comment: yes, I'm using the default logger

Comment: I think the best way would be to use a specific tool to view and filter the logs. But sometimes that may be an overkill - then I would consider switching to Serilog. Should be a small change.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if this is a good idea, but you can disable logging for a specific `DbContext` with something like that

```c#
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

    optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddFilter(_ => false);
    }));
}
```

Comment: That's for a context *class*, not per instance, as OP wants seemingly.

Comment: Well, I see nothing about instances in the question. Hope OP tell me if I got it wrong

Comment: Gert is right, if I do so my entire Db logs will be suppressed. I want it for a specific 
query or instance